# c++ adding one by one to array till full

Tags: c++, arrays, function, boolean, void

I'm trying to add one grade at a to the array till full then I need to return as true.

**Void that i'm using** = cpp.sh/9np2

Here is the code

```
void GetGrades(StatsList* stats)
{
  ListType grade = 0;
  while (grade != -1)
 {
    cout << "Enter grade (-1 quits):";
    cin >> grade;
    if (!cin)
    {
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(2000, '\n');
        cout << "Invalid number" << endl;
    }
    else if (grade >= MINGRADE && grade <= MAXGRADE)
    {       
        if (!stats->NewGrade(grade))
        {
            cout << grade << " not entered - grade list is full" << endl;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (grade != -1)
            cout << "Grade out of range" << endl;
    }

 }
}
```

**class function that i'm using** = cpp.sh/2jkz

```
bool StatsList::NewGrade(ListType grade)
{
  int i = 0;
  bool full = (List[6] == '\0');

  if (full){
      List[i] = grade;
      i++;
      cout << grade;
 }
  return false;
}
```

I tired **AF** and I can't seem to figure it out what I'm doing wrong please help a girl out. I just want to understand what i'm doing wrong before I got to bed.

Comment: i'm sorry first time using this site let me try to fix

Comment: Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). Then [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: is it me or does your NewGrade function always return false ???

Comment: Two things, please ask an actual qiestion, and consider using `std::vector` over a 'primative' assuming you don't know about `std::list`

Comment: OP knows the maximum size of `List` why put up with the extra overhead of a `vector` when a fixed size array will do? I can see a  case for `std::array` but I'd even call that a bit excessive here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `bool StatsList::NewGrade(ListType grade)` there are a couple problems.

1. `i` needs to persist from call to call otherwise it will always be set to 0 at the beginning of the function. I recommend giving it a more descriptive name like `listindex` and making it a member variable.
2. There is no `return true`. The logical place to put it appears to be at the end inside the `if (full)` body.

A word on `full`. `full` is true if `List` is **not** full. The untruth in this  naming will only mislead people and result in errors injected by people maintaining the code in the future. I recommend changing the name or changing the way it is used. Changing the name seems more logical to me.

Comment: So I change i to listindex and make listindex apart of my class as a public variable?

Comment: Recommend a `private` variable because the class's users have no need for direct access to the list index and can cause a great deal of harm with it. Eg. `obj.listindex=100;` index will now be out of range and the program's behaviour unpredictable. If `listindex` is private a mistake like that will raise a compiler error. General rule of thumb is make all data `private` and allow limited access through access functions unless you have a really, really, **really** good reason not to. For more, the search keyword is "data hiding".